# c# Excel Why is it removing duplicates from cells as apposed to whole row?

Tags: c#, excel, duplicates, removeall

I've done some searching around and the function I have found doesn't seem to be working how i expect, am i passing in the wrong parameters?

I want to remove all duplicate row entries within an excel spreadsheet using c#.

```
Range theRange = workSheet.UsedRange as Range;
theRange.RemoveDuplicates(XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);
```

What it seems to do is just remove rows that have any duplicate cell values as apposed to looking at the row as a whole.

What am I doing wrong? When I go into excel and click on Data >> Remove duplicates and have all columns selected then it will give me what i want. What is programmatic way of of doing this?

`Removeduplicates` seems to be rather quick so i don't want to do any sort of loops etc.

Comment: I know why is that, but I have no idea how to solve it. When you go to Data >> Remove duplicates >> you set up a filter on a set, so remove duplicates works on a set where each row is a seperate data entity (record). Hence it works as expected. Maybe you need to follow the same routine of selecting the dataset first?

Answer (score 4):

Your question has been bugging me all day, and I have finally figured it out!

You need to specify the column number that you wish to remove duplicates from.

Even though you have already specified the range, you still need to specify the column. The description is misleading in that it states this as optional, and indicates that if this is left blank, the entire range will be searched for duplicates. This is not true.

The description is more misleading in that it says that this can be an object array. The only way that you can specify columns is by number, and passing an array of integers into this method causes a runtime error.

The second boolean parameter you pass into this method works as expected, it allows you to declare that the first cell in the column contains the title.

The following code works for me, in regards to removing duplicates from column one:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace RemoveDupes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var excel = new Excel.Application();
            var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Test\Test.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

            var usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

            usedRange.RemoveDuplicates(1);

            workbook.Close(true);

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        }
    }
}
```